# How to configure IIS authentication for ASP.NET Core application to use SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, asp.net-core

I want to know whats the best way to configure IIS authentication. We have asp.net core application which get deployed through an installer. The problem is that Integrated security= True does not work when app tries to access SQL Server whether on same machine or on LAN. But if connection string is set to Integrated security=False and provide User Id and password which is set in Sql server it works fine. So whats the best way to handle it during Installation when User/Admin get to choose whether to use Sql server  or Windows authentication, when user chooses Windows, all installer does is set Integrated security= True in .json file. Do we need to do anything else? which user should it be on a windows server? Thank you very much.

Comment: What user is the application pool running as? Does that user have permissions in SQL Server?

Comment: I tried all four of them, we dont know, like sometimes SQL server would be installed on same machine or sometimes on different machine on the network. Is it network services option that should be set for that application pool and create account in SQL server for that machine name ?

Comment: For applications that use integrated security and SQL Server is on a different machine, I never use any of the built in accounts. We always create a new account in AD and use that to run the application pool. Usually something like "DOMAIN\AppNameProductionAppPool".

Comment: Doesn't it that mean currently app running on a machine has account in AD, so i created a login in SQL server by that machine name like cc\machinename$ this is what app is trying to access the database as login name, found that in SSMS profile trace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create SQL Server login associated with ASP.Net network service or custom account and map it to databases with corresponding role ('db_owner' role has a full access).
[See also](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx)

Comment: Is it the Application pool that the app is running under needs this info from IIS side?

Comment: [The application pool identity is associated with built-in or custom account](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(v=ws.10).aspx) and you should link it with SQL Server login.